# abstract algebra poly question

Tags: abstract-algebra

Over the field $\text{GF}(5)$, find all zeros of $x^2+2x+2$
Then factor the polynomial into the product of a constant term and irreducible monic polynomials.

I found the root is 1, and I found $x^2+2x+2=(x+4)(x+3)$, but the problem says "factor the polynomial into the product of a constant term and irreducible monic polynomials."

how can I factor as a constant term and irreducible monic polynomials? Is 1  the constant which I already did or not..a bit confused..

Comment: Yes, the constant factor $= 1$ in your factorization, so you are done. Generally it will be the leading coefficient when all the other factors are monic.

Comment: "I found the root is $1$" is a bit imprecise, you found that a root is $1$. Another is $2$.